# User session management in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

my client has had a security audit of a system I built for them complete.

They want it to work in such a way that if a user logs in via Internet Explorer that when they login via Firefox on the same machine (or via IE on another machine) that it kills the first session.

Essentially this means storing session info in the DB i would imagine and then setting an active/inactive flag against it so user id, session id, status if userid has an active session, then kill first session, and create new session.

Are there any built in mechanisms for doing this with the .NET framework or can anyone point me in the direction of some tutorials etc.

Many thanks,

Ed

Comment: Can you clarify please. If the user logs in from another machine/browser then their session in the other browsers ceases and continues in the new browser?

Comment: yes correct - user logs in from another machine/browser and their session in other browsers ceases and continues in the new browser

Comment: @Ian: I agree the "Spec" is too loose,  What if another instance of IE is used? IOW are we saying that universally only one browser process may have an active session for a user?

Comment: @Ed, please edit you question to tighten the requirement.

Comment: @Anthony - if another instance of IE is used, then I would consider this to be the same session - that's if the server has a hard time differentiating sessions from within the same browser container (i.e. multiple IE windows).

Comment: @Anthony - Also, a user might click "Open in new window" etc. which would make sense that the session be sustained.
The recommendation is designed to stop users sharing their login credentials on different pc's and allowing 2 users to login at the same time with the same login.

Comment: @Ed, see my comment to the answer for Chris.  I think you will find his answer will do what you need.  If a user starts a fresh instance of IE and logs in it would be reasonable in this scenario to block the older instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a field to your users table to store the currently used session ID.  This ID is easily accessible from your code.  When the user logs in, store that ID.

On every page request, check to verify that the current session ID matches what was stored in your user table.  If it doesn't match, then clear the current session data and kick the user back to the log in screen.

This will not stop the user from using multiple tabs in IE 7 because IE7 uses the same instance for each tab; but it will stop them from using multiple browser instances.

The reason why this will work is that each browser contains it's own cookie space.  Session's are matched up server side based on a cookie value that stores the session id and is sent back to the server on each request.

Incidentally, this is not a very effective means of eliminating session hijacking; which it sounds like the security audit is trying to prevent.  If you need to do that, update your question and I'll go further.

**UPDATE**

One way to stop session hijacking is to store a random number in the session and as a cookie on the browser.  When the next request comes in, verify that the cookie and session values match.  If they don't then reset the session id variable in your user table.  This will force all sessions to log in again.  For every page request (post / get) create a new random value.  The downside is that pages can not be bookmarked; but that's probably acceptable.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - this might work but I'd like the "new" session to override the "old" one so the user is not kicked out. But if they went back to the original browser/pc and refresh or tried to access something they would be thrown back to the login

Comment: That's exactly what this would do.  Each time they log in, just update the user table with the latest session id.  When the old one does a get or post it'll see that it's not current then you redirect to the login screen.

Comment: Ed, that's basically what I did. Last in wins, otherwise you have to wait for their session to timeout before letting them log back in.

Comment: @Chris: Change "stop them from using multiple browser windows" to "multiple browers instances", multiple windows launched from the current instance of the browser will use the same session.

Comment: @Chris - yes, this "last in wins" approach seems to be the way to go. What else would recommend to stop session hijacking? 
@Anthony - ahh yes, the old "browser instances" vs. "browser windows" chestnut - has confused many a web developer.

Answer (score 0):

I [blogged](http://jberke.blogspot.com/2008/10/limiting-concurent-users-in-aspnet.html) about how I handle this. Basically the idea is we create a non-persistant cookie, which has a Guid.

We then store this tied to the userId in some place on the server (App Cache, DB etc...). We then have a poller which hits the server every couple of minutes, and if the cookie doesn't match the value, we log the user out.

Comment: @Josh - nice approach - certainly has given me food for thought